# Можно ли удалять из конструкции switch определенный case после его использования?

Tags: c#, switch, case

Можно ли сделать так, что бы к определённому case можно было обратиться только 1 раз, то есть после выполнения кода например в case 1, этот кейс удалялся.

Comment: нет, и точка...

Comment: Cпасибо, понял.

Comment: Поожалуйста, давайте вопросам осмысленные заголовки. Представьте сайт, на котором все заголовки вопросов были бы "Здравствуйте, начал учить с# и у меня появился такой вопрос"

Comment: Вам хочется странного. Расскажите вашу _настоящую_ проблему: зачем вам это? Что вы пытаетесь таким образом сделать? Скорее всего, вы идёте неправильным путём.

Comment: Всегда хотел иметь возможность писать самомодифицирующийся код. PS: кто сказал "антивирусы"?

Comment: `нет, и точка...`, это наивный ответ, а правильные ответы - "конечный автомат", "стек и очередь". @VladD очевидно же, зачем :) просто вопрос - XY проблема.

Answer (score 2):

Я могу предложить следующее решение.

Допустим, изначально был такой код:

```
int n = ...;

switch (n)
{
    case 1:
        Console.WriteLine("one");
        break;

    case 2:
        Console.WriteLine("two");
        break;

    default:
        Console.WriteLine("default");
        break;
}
```

Код со свитчем переписывается компилятором в поиск по словарю. Давайте вручную перепишем его с использованием Dictionary.

Определяем словарь:

```
var dict = new Dictionary<int, Action>
{
    { 1, () => Console.WriteLine("one") },
    { 2, () => Console.WriteLine("two") },
};
```

Здесь в виде `Action` заданы ветки `case`. Только ветка `default` отсутствует.
Использование при этом выглядит так:

```
int n = 2;
dict[n]();
```

Однако, если задать ключ, которого нет в словаре, будет выброшено исключение. Поэтому нужно обрабатывать этот случай:

```
int n = 3;

if (dict.TryGetValue(n, out Action action))
    action();
else
    Console.WriteLine("default");
```

Теперь добавим в код удаление уже выполненных кейсов:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
{
    for (int n = 0; n < 4; n++)
    {
        if (dict.TryGetValue(n, out Action action))
        {
            action();
            dict.Remove(n);
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("default");
        }
    }
    Console.WriteLine();
}
```

На первой итерации внешнего цикла будут выполнены ветки, выводящие "one" и "two", после чего эти `Action` удаляются из словаря методом `Remove`.

На второй итерации срабатывают только дефолтные условия.

Answer (score 1):

Нет, так делать нельзя.
Если вы хотите сделать выполнение кода 1 раз вам стоит либо ввести дополнительную переменную-флаг типа bool в которой вы будете показывать использовалась ли та часть кода и перед использованием делать проверку, либо сделать функцию, которую вы вызовете 1 раз.